# GetStream RestApi error => Errors for fields 'actor', 'verb', 'object'

Tags: getstream-io, rest

I am trying to send a post request to getstream using postman. I am not able to do that. I am getting the following error:-

```
{
    "detail": "Errors for fields 'actor', 'verb', 'object'",
    "status_code": 400,
    "code": 4,
    "exception": "InputException",
    "exception_fields": {
        "actor": [
            "actor is a required field"
        ],
        "object": [
            "object is a required field"
        ],
        "verb": [
            "verb is a required field"
        ]
    },
    "duration": "0.21ms"
}
```

I am unable to solve the problem. I didn't find any documentation for sending post request. Maybe that's because I am beginner too. Anyway can anyone tell me how I can send a post request to getstream api using postman ????
Thanks!

Comment: could you share your body so that we can tweak together ?

Comment: @ferhatelmas Note that I am a beginner ok :)

Body:

{
    "changes": [
        {
            "id": "32caf720-ea5a-11ea-8080-80007cd50a60",
            "actor": [
                "SU:b625d462b0080fbd418ac660f22255c6"
            ],
            "object": [
                "SU:1c4b2e21c863a637e27d1646d18ffcbd"
            ],
            "verb": [
                "waves"
            ],
            "set": {
                "is_seen": true
            }
        }
    ]
}